Understanding Why this Question is Closed
I posted “Waiting” for the answer to the ultimate questions which was closed by 5 users as opinion-based. Can someone help me out and explain why this question was closed?

You seem to have copied that question over. What is needed is just  a link. You perhaps want to ask a meta question about the closure. You must do that explicitly on this meta site

@Rushi The guy who closed this question there asked me to post it here.

Yes but post doesn't mean post . Post means ask about — Why closed? How to improve? Etc

@Etc Oh I see. So what exactly does philosophy meta site do?

Discusses issues regarding main, in your case Why was my question (on main) closed?

@Rushi Hey thanks for the clarification. I reposted the correct question, hopefully.

Voting to close as a dup of the question asking to reopen this question on Main - Question regarding "strategy of life" closed for being "opinion-based".

(Or you could just delete this question, given that it's beyond the scope of Meta, as it isn't discussing the working of the site.)

@NotThatGuy Or you simply could help a bruh, and fix it instead of getting you VTC on.

@DanielMendoza Okay. I've addressed how to use the site more generally. On the Meta site, the questions are not about philosophy, but about how to use the site to do a Q&A-based approach to finding philosophical answers.

@JD Well... now it's just much more directly a duplicate of the Meta question asking how they can improve their Main question, and it should still be closed.

@NotThatGuy Outstanding! I can see why your current employer values you.

@JD ??? .......

@NotThatGuy (You're thorough. I didn't think to look.)

Okay,
So you're new to the site. Welcome! :D
The philosophy that is done here is not the what-do-you-think variety that is done at the thephilosophyforum.com. At that site, your post would do well, because people engage in actual philosophical discourse. Here, we do Q&A, which essentially is asking a short, fact-based question, and (with a bit of luck) receiving some fact-based responses from published sources.

So, what do you think of Kant?

Boo!

What distinction did Kant devise in the Critique of Pure Reason to X?

Yay!
Thus, your question:

If one’s life goal is to understand these ultimate questions and their solutions, should they focus on longevity in order to wait for humanity to develop the necessary technology, philosophy, or language?

Is very much not canonical; that is to say, there is no one right answer, and since this site strives to avoid being a forum for arguing philosophy, respondents are generally confined to answering like a librarian (though the separation is often not maintained rigorously for several reasons especially not everyone agrees on what fact-based Q&A means).
The best post on the Meta side to explain the spirit of this norm on the site is: Friends, we are not philosophers
Thus, you are not asking about philosophy, but are attempting to do philosophy, which can be hard at times to differentiate. So don't take closure personally, and if you stick around, just remember you should ask factual questions about philosophy, but not ask anyone to philosophize, which you have to do on your own time and your own website. :D

If you haven't, reread https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help which is the "manual". (Yes, I'm RTFMing you.) If you tag me using the @ symbol on my response, I can address any additional clarification you might have in how to deal with the VTC (vote to close) process, which is a bit contentious at times.

Thanks for the clarification. I’ll try posting on the Philosophy Forum instead. It does require an invitation code, so I emailed them as instructed and am hoping they’ll respond.

@DanielMendoza Probably for the best. Use this site if you have a specific technical question. For instance, if you get into an argument about utterances and propositions, and you want to determine how utterances and propositions differ, this would be the better site to get affirmation of the correct answer.
